# JQuery Mobile Loses All Styles After Navigating Pages

Tags: javascript, css, ajax, jquery-mobile

Im going through a serious headache, for the last few hours I cant figure out why when I flick between pages (dynamically loaded by ajax) that the styling all goes.

I have read dozens of posts on the net about this, and have tried .page() trigger("Refresh") trigger create and many more.

Page 1 has a list, on click of the item it fetches the complete contents of another list and put them into the DOM.

JQuery Versions (mobile 1.1rc2 - but same issue with 1.0.1 stable):

```
<script src="scripts/ajax.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/latest/jquery.mobile.css">
```

This link is clicked on initial list:

```
javascript:GetGarageList("G9236")
```

which triggers :

```
// show garages for factor
function GetGarageList(accNo) {
    $.mobile.showPageLoadingMsg("b", "Loading", false);
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "Default.aspx/GetGarageList",
        data: "{'accNo':'" + accNo + "'}",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (msg) {
            $("#garageList").html(msg.d);
            $.mobile.changePage("#garageList");
        },
        error: function () {
            ShowError("Error :(");
        },
        complete: function () {
            $.mobile.hidePageLoadingMsg();
        }
    });
};
```

On first load, the 2nd page looks perfect :

[image]

But when I press back button up top. Then click another link :

```
javascript:GetGarageList("G9336")
```

I get messed up view :

[image]

Please help!

EDIT :

Others have used .trigger("create"); and say they solved the problem... but everytime I add that to my code like so :

```
$("#garageList").html(msg.d).trigger("create");
```

or

```
$("#garageList").html(msg.d);
$("#garageList").trigger("create");
```

It just gives me a loading spinner forever.

EDIT 2:

As per Barnes suggestion below I have changed the html as so :

```
    <%--Garage List--%>
    <div data-role="page" id="garageList" data-add-back-btn="true" data-theme="a">
        <div data-role='header' data-position='fixed'>
            <h1>Garages</h1>
            <a href='index.html' data-icon='plus' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-right' data-theme='b'></a>
        </div>
        <div data-role='content' id="abc">
            <ul data-role='listview' id='xyz' data-filter='true' data-filter-theme='a' data-filter-placeholder='search name or account no...' data-split-icon='info' data-split-theme='a'>

/// --> new content goes here... as simply many <li> items.

</ul>
        </div> <!-- /content -->
    </div> <!-- /page -->
```

Then I tried (in the ajax success):

```
            $("#xyz").empty();
            $("#xyz").html(msg.d);
            $("#abc").listview("refresh");
            $.mobile.changePage("#garageList");
```

AND

```
            $("#xyz").html(msg.d);
            $("#xyz").listview("refresh");
            $.mobile.changePage("#garageList");
```

HERE is some sample output of msg.d :

```
"<li><a href='javascript:GetGarageDetails(16267)'><h3>A KETCHEN MOTOR ENGINEERS</h3><p><strong>MID LOTHIAN</strong></p></a><a href="javascript:GetFactorDetails('16267')"></a></li>

<li><a href='javascript:GetGarageDetails(16328)'><h3>G.A.AUTOS</h3><p><strong></strong></p></a><a href="javascript:GetFactorDetails('16328')"></a></li>

<li><a href='javascript:GetGarageDetails(16262)'><h3>GARRY HENDERSON MOTOR ENGINEERS</h3><p><strong>WEST LIMTON</strong></p></a><a href="javascript:GetFactorDetails('16262')"></a></li>

<li><a href='javascript:GetGarageDetails(16264)'><h3>LEADBURN GARAGE LTD</h3><p><strong>PEELBLESHIRE</strong></p></a><a href="javascript:GetFactorDetails('16264')"></a></li>

<li><a href='javascript:GetGarageDetails(16315)'><h3>LOTHIAN MOTORS</h3><p><strong></strong></p></a><a href="javascript:GetFactorDetails('16315')"></a></li>

"
```

And other variations, but it still doesnt want to play (spinner goes on forever on refresh) ... although its improved a little (when I take the refresh out) :

[image]

Comment: You are not alone on this one. I have tried the trigger("create") method a bunch of times too. I can't seem to figure it out either.

Comment: Does your list use the data-role="listview" attribute? If so you can call refresh on the listview: $("#garageList").listview("refresh");

Comment: E-Barnes, hi I tried that it didnt work. Also the docs say that refresh is meant when you append to the DOM. But in my case Im replacing the contents of everything inside the page div with a brand new listview.

Comment: Gotcha. After doing ajax calls like yours, I usually append the new data to my listview, leaving the header/search bar/footer html untouched. Is there a reason you need to replace the whole page instead of just the list itself?

Comment: Also, sometimes I call $('myListView').empty(); if I need to replace all the content in the list with the new data. In either case, this lets me use the 'refresh' call to update the styles. It's one of my least favorite parts of jQuery Mobile.

Comment: Hi e.barnes, please see my edit 2 above.

Comment: My only thoughts would be to make sure the <ul> is not being overwritten when you add the new data using .html(). Also it might be worth trying .append(msg.d) to see if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has been solving all of my problems.

```
$('...').trigger('create');
```

You just have to find the right element to put in the selector.

For me, these lines did the trick:

```
$(document).bind('pagechange', function() {
  $('.ui-page-active .ui-listview').listview('refresh');
  $('.ui-page-active :jqmData(role=content)').trigger('create');
});
```

Comment: I came back to this later when I needed to style stuff on the same page (after a search), I just used the two lines inside the "pagechange" function after injecting my results html code and it worked :)

Comment: I was losing styling when using jQuery's "append" method on a div. Triggering the create event on the element I'm appending, helped add all of the css styles back in in the jquery mobile views. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Placing `listview('refresh')` after changing the page solved my problem.

```
$.mobile.changePage("#catalog");

$('#list_included_in_catalog_page').listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
success: function (msg) {
    $("#garageList").html(msg.d);
    $.mobile.changePage("#garageList");
}
```

Do

```
success: function (msg) {
    $("#abc").html("&lt;ul data-role='listview' id='xyz' data-filter='true' data-filter-theme='a' data-filter-placeholder='search name or account no...' data-split-icon='info' data-split-theme='a'&gt; " + msg.d + "&lt;ul&gt;");
    $.mobile.changePage("#garageList");
    $("#abc").find(":jqmData(role=listview)").listview();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After trying everything I settled for a less than ideal solution of using seperate .aspx pages.

But now this had the issue that I had to pass the parameters now in the URL between pages (security risk).

So instead of using :

```
javascript:GetGarageList("G9236")
```

I now use a guid instead :

```
http://localhost:54419/GarageList.aspx?id=319d8819-11ae-446f-b373-50d08e06159a
```

I generate the new page in the c# page load event :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Write("<div data-role='page' id='garageList' data-add-back-btn='true' data-theme='a'>");
        Response.Write("<div data-role='header' data-position='fixed'>");
        Response.Write("<h1>Garages</h1>");
        Response.Write("<a href='index.html' data-icon='plus' data-iconpos='notext' class='ui-btn-right' data-theme='b'></a>");
        Response.Write("</div>");

        Response.Write("<div data-role='content'>");
        Response.Write("<ul data-role='listview' data-filter='true' data-filter-theme='a' data-filter-placeholder='search name or account no...' data-split-icon='info' data-split-theme='a'>");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString["id"]))
        {
            Guid guid = Guid.Parse(Request.QueryString["id"]);
            using (DbContext db = new DbContext())
            {
                var f = db.Factors.Where(x => x.Guid == guid).SingleOrDefault();
                if (f != null)
                {
                    foreach (var g in f.Garages.OrderBy(x => x.Name))
                    {
                        Response.Write(String.Format("<li><a href='javascript:GetGarageDetails({0})'><h3>{1}</h3><p><strong>{2}</strong></p></a><a href='#' /></li>", g.Guid, g.Name, g.Town));
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        Response.Write("</ul>");
        Response.Write("</div>");
        Response.Write("</div>");
    }
```

This works pretty well, but I noticed some remnants of previous pages got left on the screen even after a page transition, this was solved by removing all the default html in the page and leaving only this line :

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="GarageList.aspx.cs" Inherits="CP.GarageList" %>
```

Now the issue I face is that the pages are super slow on my mobile device.

Answer (score 0):

You need to refresh your list. 
e.g.)

```
$('Some DiV').listview('refresh');
```

Answer (score 0):

The calls of jquery mobile to other pages, are with ajax and sometimes this produces a failure when loading styles and libraries.

When I use redirect an external page I use `window.location.href`.

A possible solution, is to correctly order the links and javascript in the header of the file, for example:

```
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no" />
<meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no" />
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery_mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery_mobile/jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.5.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_mobile/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery_mobile/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<title>my page</title></head>
```