# Backbone and JQuery Mobile: Unbind events after a page transition

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js

I want to unbind all events when I change a page. I took [this solution](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/01/backbone-js-lessons-learned-and-improved-sample-app) which extends the View's close function with this.unbind() call and I tried to combine it with JQM page transitions in a changePage function in the Router from [here](http://coenraets.org/blog/2012/03/using-backbone-js-with-jquery-mobile/):

```
changePage: function(page){
        $(page.el).attr("data-role", "page");
        page.render();
        $("body").append($(page.el));
        var transition = $.mobile.defaultPageTransition;
        if(this.firstPage){
            transition = "none",
            this.firstPage = false;
        }
        $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {changeHash: false, transition: transition});
    }
```

Then changePage looks like this:

```
changePage: function(page){
        if (this.currentView)
            this.currentView.close();
        $(page.el).attr("data-role", "page");
        this.currentView = page;
        page.render();
        $("body").append($(page.el));
        var transition = $.mobile.defaultPageTransition;
        if(this.firstPage){
            transition = "none",
            this.firstPage = false;
        }
        $.mobile.changePage($(page.el), {changeHash: false, transition: transition});
    }
```

But then I get the JQM error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method '_trigger' of undefined jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js:2788
transitionPages jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js:2788
$.mobile.changePage jquery.mobile-1.1.0.js:3390
window.AppRouter.Backbone.Router.extend.changePage
```

I also have jqm-config.js which removes the page's DOM on pagehide event. Could I unbind all events here like: `$(event.currentTarget).unbind();` ? But this doesn't work either.

```
  $('div[data-role="page"]').live('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
    $(event.currentTarget).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. The JQM error occurs because you try to call `this.remove()` in `close()` backbone extended method, but the event "pagehide" has already removed the view from the DOM.

```
Backbone.View.prototype.close = function () {
    if (this.beforeClose) {
        this.beforeClose();
    }
    this.remove();
    this.unbind();
};
```

If you comment `this.remove()` on *close* method, it works.

Another option is to comment `$(event.currentTarget).remove();` on *pagehide* jqmobile event and doesn't comment `this.remove()` on *close* method.

You can't do both, you should choose one of the two options. I prefer the second option, but I think that it's similar to first option. I don't recommend call `unbind()` on *pagehide* event.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem, for some reason the pagechange event was not being fired and the previous pages were not removed from the DOM. Once I removed the non-active pages the CSS was back in action.

So I added

```
    $('div[data-role="page"]').bind('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
        $(event.currentTarget).remove();
    });
```

inside

```
     $(document).bind('pagechange', function() {

     });
```

So my jqm-config.js looks like this

```
$(document).bind("mobileinit", function () {
     console.log('mobileinit');
     $.mobile.ajaxEnabled = false;
     $.mobile.linkBindingEnabled = false;
     $.mobile.hashListeningEnabled = false;
     $.mobile.pushStateEnabled = false;
//$.mobile.defaultPageTransition = "none";
});

  $(document).bind('pagechange', function() {
    $('div[data-role="page"]').bind('pagehide', function (event, ui) {
        console.log("Removing page");
        $(event.currentTarget).remove();
    });
});
```

It took me a few hours and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10092111/jquery-mobile-loses-all-styles-after-navigating-pages) SO thread to get to this. Hope this helps someone.